# OnKeyDown for Android not working in Delphi 10.4.1

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, onkeydown

I'm aware of this link:
[No OnKeyDown event for Return key on Delphi Android 10.3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59851405/no-onkeydown-event-for-return-key-on-delphi-android-10-3-3)

which @blong had given a solution in 10.3.3

Looking at the code in 10.4.1, it seems that Embarcadero had removed the ELSE block as @blong had suggested.  Looks like it's possible Embarcadero monitors this forum for fixed posted by users.

EDITED: this code is from Delphi's source code in FMXEditText.java (detailed source code not included as it's Embarcadero's source).

```
@Override
public void onEditorAction(int actionCode) {
    // Disable default processing logic of ReturnKey.
    if (actionCode == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
        ...
        ...
    }
    // Delegate handle Editor action to FMX side.
    for (FMXTextListener listener : listeners) {
        listener.onEditorAction(actionCode);
    }
}
```

However, the OnKeyDown still does not work in Delphi 10.4.1

Please advise how I can get OnKeyDown to work for a TEdit in 10.4.1.
iOS works fine, so it's unimaginable why would Android version be so restrictive.

Any gurus out here who knows how to over-ride the Android system?

Thanks.

Comment: He posted Java code from FMXEditText.java, which is part of the Delphi source

Comment: For what it's worth: it's an epic struggle even for Java developers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24425998/3164070. It might help to know *why* you want to use the event, because there might be an alternate solution

Comment: I'm trying to do an internal table incremental search (which is fast anyway for incremental), and I don't want the user to have to press the 'Return' key after each keystroke. Thanks for any inputs.

Comment: @KenWhite I have edited the post to clarify it's source code from Embarcadero's source units.